# Conversion from XSLX to TXT asks for exit method

Tags: python

As per other posts I saw on stackoverflow, I wrote the following code to convert an XLSX to TXT however it throws: AttributeError: **exit** :

```
import xlrd
import csv

with xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx').sheet_by_index(0) as in_xslx:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_xslx) 
    with open("data.txt", "w", newline='', encoding='utf8') as out_text:
        out_writer = csv.writer(out_text, delimiter = '\t')
        for row in in_reader:
            out_writer.writerow(row)
```

However it successfully converts a CSV if I replace the first two rows with:

```
with open("data.csv", "r", encoding='utf-8') as in_csv:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_csv)
```

Any idea why is that happening when converting XSLX->TXT and how to correct?

Thank you

Comment: Absolutely not! Excel files are not simple text files. You cannot do an i/o read write like that. Use dedicated handlers for such a format.

Comment: Tiny.D's code works perfectly with the exception of adding ,encoding='utf-8' to initial open statement

Comment: Indeed, @TinyD's code does not attempt to read spreadsheet with `open` as you did but uses actual Excel handlers like `xlrd`.

Comment: Haha yeah it was a bad copy paste on my part while appropriating query from CSV->TXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
import xlrd
import csv

with open("data.txt", "w") as out_text:
    # define output writer
    out_writer = csv.writer(out_text, delimiter = '\t')
    # Open and read an Excel file
    data_file = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')
    # get the first worksheet
    worksheet= data_file.sheet_by_index(0)
    # get the row values and write into output file
    for rownum in xrange( worksheet.nrows ):
        out_writer.writerow(worksheet.row_values(rownum))
```

Comment: I get " a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ".
P.S. I am on windows machine

Comment: change the open mode from `wb` to `w`.

Comment: yup and added encoding for utf8. Thanks!